# Detecting System Time Edits

Tags: java, macos, datetime, operating-system, unix-timestamp

I want to know whether system time in Mac OS X is changed by the user or not ? Is there any way to detect it? A Java solution would be preferred, but I will accept any. Actually, I need to reset a value in my application whenever system time will be changed by user, so I am looking for a callback function or API which can notify me that system time is changed forcefully by user not automatically.

Comment: I doubt you can do this. Could you explain the use case in a little more detail?

Comment: Maybe you can use an internet clock?

Comment: @NPE I am currently working on a realtime application which needs to track time. I am using time from time server but problem is suppose i need to use time then i will request to server but it will take some time to get time from server so at the starting of my application i will save server time and update it manually. I want to update it without using threads. So i am using system time to calculate difference and adding it to server time. But if system time will change then how to update server time so i need such callback function.

Comment: You might do that for display purposes, but any time you do anything important you should be reading the time from the server and using that value directly.  Never trust the client's clock.

Comment: Also note that most operating systems (including Mac OS X) have clock synchronization built in, and the OS can invoke this with or without the user's involvement.  [See here](http://superuser.com/a/155788)

Comment: Actually i am looking for time difference which should accurate always. Local watch cannot give me that and server time will take some time to get from server as application is realtime and tightly bound with time so i cannot wait for server to response me.